# - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:

Tags: ios, boolean, settings

maybe someone could assist me.

When my app is launched for the first time a UIAlertController message appears and asks the user if they Need to GoTo the Settings App. using the following code.

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=Wi-Fi"]];
        });
```

Upon return to the App the same UIAlertController Message appears, using this code in the ViewDidLoad:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
  if (launched == NO) {
     launched = YES; 
    defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setBool:launched forKey:@"boolKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    My code for the UIAlertController.

   } else if (launched == YES) {

   [self doSomeThing];
  }

}
```

It appears my Bool Value is not being saved when the settings in the info.plist Application does not run in background: is set to YES, but if the Application does not run in background: is set to NO the else statement is executed. However this is not good because my app is suspended and when launched again I need the original message to appear and it does not, the app is restored to its last state.

Any Suggestions is greatly appreciated.

JZ

Answer (score 1):

1.- Saving into NSUserDefaults does not save anything to the info.plist. NSUserDefaults has its own plist that gets wiped out if you remove your application.

If you want to prevent to launch the same alertview:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if([defaults boolForKey:@"boolKey"]) {
    defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"boolKey"];
    My code for the UIAlertController.
}
else {
     //Whatever you need to do if its not first launch
}
```

Now next time you hit your viewDidLoad, since the boolForKey:@"boolKey" has a YES, you won't hit that code and the alertView won't get presented.

Comment: you also need to add `[defaults synchronize]` after you set the bool value to save it

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help !!! It worked perfectly. I did not realize I missed that piece.

Comment: Please @JohnZ  vote my answer as the correct one so it will help others